# How can I write semantic tagging in grxml with some prefix number?

Tags: xml, speech-recognition, grammar, voice-recognition

I am building a GRXML grammar for a software that will use nuance  for voice recognition. The tags must follow the tag-format "swi-semantics/1.0"
following are the logic

1. 7 digits or
2. 4 digit or 7 Digits
   a) if 4 digits enter i.e 1234 translate it into with prefix 101 like 1011234
   b) 7 digits start with 101 + 4 digit.

I am new with the grammar. I am confuse how can i add the prefix 101.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tags to return any value you want after a semantic match.
This is documentation from Microsoft/Tellme, but it has very good information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/ee800146(v=msdn.10)

The Microsoft examples use the W3C standard tag-format "semantics/1.0" which is supported by Nuance. The syntax for swi-semantics/1.0 is a little different but the concepts are the same. I believe swi-semantics/1.0 tags do not use the EcmaScript out variable to return named values.

In swi-semantics/1.0 a value would be returned like:

```
<tag>YesNo='yes'</tag>
```

In semantics/1.0, a value would be returned like:

```
<tag>out.YesNo='yes'</tag>
```